# Python app on heroku platform seems to start on two threads

Tags: python, multithreading, heroku, web-applications

There is a simple python app which is deployed on heroku platform:

```
from flask import Flask

log("APP STARTED.")
# single time connection to database and logging stuff

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
# do something

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
# do something
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-
```

When looking into logs i see that my code above was executed multiple times with multiple threads. I know that there must be more threads involved because of the inconsistent logging. See log:

```
2017-05-31T17:12:46.415059+00:00 app[web.1]: APP STARTED.   
2017-05-31T17:12:46.415072+00:00 app[web.1]: Executing query.  
2017-05-31T17:12:46.415688+00:00 app[web.1]: APP STARTED.    
2017-05-31T17:12:46.415717+00:00 app[web.1]: Executing query.
2017-05-31T17:12:46.436370+00:00 app[web.1]: Successful connection to database.    
2017-05-31T17:12:46.437398+00:00 app[web.1]: Successful connection to database.    
2017-05-31T17:12:46.439197+00:00 app[web.1]: Success executing query.    
2017-05-31T17:12:46.439680+00:00 app[web.1]: Success executing query.
```

Also i can see worker threads here:

```
2017-05-31T18:59:10.046388+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-05-31 18:59:10 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9    
2017-05-31T18:59:10.132547+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-05-31 18:59:10 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
```

***How do i prevent multiple worker-threads booting up and start only with one?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is expected behavior. Note that those are not threads, but child processes. By default, `gunicorn` is a forking server - to handle concurrent requests, it creates multiple sub-processes.

You see two worker processes because, according to the docs (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#basic-configuration), `gunicorn` honors the `WEB_CONCURRENCY` environment variable, which seems to default to two on Heroku.

You can replicate the behavior locally very directly, via `WEB_CONCURRENCY=2 heroku local`; note the two worker pids. Then run it without the `WEB_CONCURRENCY` variable, and you'll see only one worker pid.

If you really want to limit it to one process, you could explicitly set `WEB_CONCURRENCY` to 1, either in a .env file or via the `heroku config:set` command. However, I advise against that -

- Since they are processes and not threads, thread synchronization is not an issue. The caveat is that you can't rely on shared state (e.g., updating module-level variables). For example, a `hit_counter` variable that gets implemented in one worker would not at all be visible in the second worker.
- Concurrency *within* the dyno will help you scale more cost effectively. `WEB_CONCURRENCY` greater than 1 lets your dyno handle multiple concurrent requests. If you limit it to 1, you'll need multiple dynos to support concurrent requests, and incur the related Heroku charges.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well. But if I set WEB_CONCURRENCY to 1 and have only the main process running i can always fork some processes manually. And by idea it is going to be the same thing as running with WEB_CONCURENCY equal to 2 lets say. Am i right ?

Comment: I advise against that - gunicorn is purpose built to manage concurrency for you. Doing it yourself introduces complexity - when to fork, when to reload, what resources to close/reopen like database connections, etc. What would you aim to accomplish by managing the processes on your own?

Comment: Well. I want to start one main process which would listen to an incoming messages and according to them it would add a task in a queue for a worker to execute (basically no calculation is done in main process). What i do is i fork my main process and with a second one every 10 minutes i refresh a database to see if a time has come to execute a command, if yes i add that command to another workers queue. 

I believe even if a forked process would take almost all the computing power of one core it would not downgrade the performance of a main process because it does almost no calculations.