# Django application deployed with Heroku/Postgresql - Some Python/JS formulas not working in production only, values jump back to previous values

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I deployed a Django application with Heroku. It works fine when I run it locally. It has a strange behavior in production. For example, when I push a button, the `Prod1` variable is supposed to increment by 1. Now sometimes it does +1, sometimes it jumps back to a previous value.
I also have a similar problem with `time.time()` but it might be related to the same issue...

That's the Django code in "Prod_settings" used in production:

```
import dj_database_url
from traineau.settings import *

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False


DATABASES['default'].update(dj_database_url.config())
MIDDLEWARE += ['whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware']
#STATICFILES_STORAGE='whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

#SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xxx.herokuapp.com']
```

As I say, everything works fine in Local so I assume the problem might be in Prod_settings..

As an exemple, these are the
[Heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoxaC.jpg)

`Prod1` variable increments correctly a couple of times and suddenly returns to 0 for no apparent reason. In this example it's zero but if I would continue it make something like (1,2,3,4,5,0,6,1,2,7,8,9,3,4....)

these are the Heroku Config vars:

```
DATABASE_URL =  postgres://xxxxx
DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC = 1
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = traineau.prod_settings
```

these are the settings used locally

```
import os
# from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
# def get_env_variable(var_name, default_value=None):
#     try:
#         return os.environ[var_name]
#     except KeyError:
#         if default_value is None:
#             error_msg = "Set the () environment variable", format(var_name)
#             raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
#         else:
#             return default_value

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__).decode('utf-8'))
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(SETTINGS_DIR).decode('utf-8')
RAW_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'raw')
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
# SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable('SECRET_KEY', 'xxx')
SECRET_KEY = 'xxx'
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xxx', 'xxx']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'traineau.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'traineau.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)

os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

And this is the python function for the +1 button:

```
def ProdL1(request):
    global StkL1, Prod1, CL1, TCL1, reload_page, timer, gTime, diffTime,batch_var
    raw_dict = {}
    print "1Prod1", Prod1


    Prod1 = Prod1 + batch_var
    raw_dict['L1Prod'] = int(Prod1)
    TCL1 = int(((time.time() -gTime)- diffTime)/(Prod1))
    raw_dict['L1TC'] = TCL1

    CL1 = TCL1 * MOL1 * C
    raw_dict['L1Cost'] = CL1
    StkL1 = StkL1 + batch_var


    seconds=int((time.time() -gTime)- diffTime)
    minutes= round(seconds/60, 2)

    print "2Prod1", Prod1
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(raw_dict), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: You can't use globals to store state like this. Different requests may be handled by different workers.

Comment: I'm not experienced python programmer so thanks for the advice. It didn't create any problem so far but I'll work on it in case. Any idea what could be the cause of my problem? The application was deployed before but not with Heroku and it worked fine. I didn't modify the Prod1 function from the previous version..

Comment: When you deployed somewhere else before, perhaps the worker(s) serving the request lived for longer so you didn’t spot any issues. To fix the problem you should store state somewhere else e.g. the database or a cache like redis.

Comment: Is there some test I can run to make sure this is the problem? Thanks

Comment: No, I can’t think of a specific test that you can run. Trust me, you shouldn’t be using globals like this. Redesign your code so that you store state somewhere else.

Comment: @Alasdair is 100% correct. I'll bet you are using gunicorn... If so, you should be able to replicate the behavior locally by setting env var `WEB_CONCURRENCY=2`. Your logs don't show a server restart, but you are clearly hitting a process with different state; on Heroku, gunicorns spawns two processes by default. See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292627/python-app-on-heroku-platform-seems-to-start-on-two-threads

Comment: @bimsapi I set WEB_CONCURRENCY = 1 and it works fine now. Thanks